# Tabs link causing broken link message with sitemap generator

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, seo

I have a Bootstrap Tabs which will show a Descriptions and Downloads tab. The sitemap generator which I am using states that the link is broken. (.downloads_tab) Obviously this would be the case as it is a class and not a link where it resolves to. Would the error go away if I use an ID reference in the href instead?

Here is my code:

```
       <div class="container-fluid">        
            <div class="col-md-12 product-info">
                <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs nav_tabs">                       
                    <li class="active" id="description_Tab" runat="server"><a href=".description_tab" data-toggle="tab">DESCRIPTION</a></li>
                    <li class="product_downloads_tab" id="downloads_Tab" runat="server"><a href=".downloads_tab" data-toggle="tab">DOWNLOADS</a></li>                   
                </ul>
                <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade in active description_tab" id="serviceone" runat="server">
                        <%=ProductDetails.ExtraInfo%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade downloads_tab" id="servicetwo" runat="server">                        
                        <%=ProductDetails.DownloadLinksHTML%>                           
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If `http://www.example.com/.downloads_tab` is a valid URL on your site then just add a leading slash. If it's not, then the sitemap generator is correct. If I had to guess, it's a CSS class, not a page name. As such, it should not be in the `href` portion of the link

Comment: It is not a valid URL. On https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp you will see that the main tab has a href with an ID. So my question is, should I just ignore the error message as this is how Bootstrap is calling a DIV when you click on a tab or should it be happy if I make it an ID instead of a class?